# Page lifecycle is causing an error with user controls within sub

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, page-lifecycle

Thanks to @Angkor Wat I achived a major step towards my goal: dynamic adding of pieces of strings to a string. But I came across another thing I cannot solve.

Here is the script:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="addtostring.aspx.vb" Inherits="demo_addtostring" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p><asp:textbox id="tb" runat="server"></asp:textbox></p>
        <asp:Panel ID="tbPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code behind:

```
Partial Class demo_addtostring
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Property gesStr As String
        Set(value As String)
            ViewState("gesStr") = value
        End Set
        Get
            Dim o As Object = ViewState("gesStr")
            If o Is Nothing Then
                Return ""
            Else
                Return o
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Page.IsPostBack Then
        Else
            gesStr = "1;"
        End If
        tb.Text = gesStr
        Dim iButton As New Button
        iButton.Text = "add"
        iButton.CommandArgument = "1;"
        iButton.CommandName = "1;"
        AddHandler iButton.Click, AddressOf add
        tbPanel.Controls.Add(iButton)

        If Page.IsPostBack Then
        Else
            anzeige()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub add(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim myButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        Dim addString As String = myButton.CommandArgument
        gesStr += addString
        tb.Text = gesStr
        anzeige()
    End Sub

    Private Sub anzeige()
        Dim gesArray As Array = Split(gesStr, ";")
        For xLauf As Integer = 0 To UBound(gesArray) - 1
            Dim anzeigeDiv As New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div")
            Dim anzLabel As New Label
            anzLabel.Text = gesArray(xLauf)
            anzeigeDiv.Controls.Add(anzLabel)
            Dim iButton2 As New Button
            iButton2.Text = xLauf.ToString
            iButton2.ID = "test" & xLauf.ToString
            iButton2.CommandArgument = "1;"
            iButton2.CommandName = "1;"
            AddHandler iButton2.Click, AddressOf add
            anzeigeDiv.Controls.Add(iButton2)
            tbPanel.Controls.Add(anzeigeDiv)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Clicking on the add-button should add "1;" to `gesStr` - the dynamic loop-generated buttons should do the same -.- Does anyone have an idea? I would be **very** thankful for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the postback to know about the event handler from the button, the button needs to be recreated prior to the point in the lifecycle where the handler is invoked. In other words, you will always need to recreate the buttons within your Page_Load.

Here is a modification to your code which works:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <p><asp:textbox id="tb" runat="server"></asp:textbox></p>
    <br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAdd" Text="add" CommandArgument="1;" />
    <asp:Panel ID="tbPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
```

And code-behind:

```
Public Property gesStr As String
    Get
        Dim o As Object = ViewState("gesStr")
        If o Is Nothing Then
            Return ""
        Else
            Return DirectCast(o, String)
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ViewState("gesStr") = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        gesStr = "1;"
    End If

    tb.Text = gesStr
End Sub

Private Sub add(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Command
    Dim addString As String = e.CommandArgument
    gesStr += addString
    tb.Text = gesStr
    CreateNewButton(tbPanel.Controls.Count, addString.Substring(0, addString.Length - 1))
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
    MyBase.CreateChildControls()

    Dim gesArray As Array = Split(gesStr, ";")
    For xLauf As Integer = 0 To UBound(gesArray) - 1
        CreateNewButton(xLauf, gesArray(xLauf))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CreateNewButton(ByVal xLauf As Integer, ByVal labelText As String)
    Dim anzeigeDiv As New Panel
    anzeigeDiv.ID = "div" & xLauf.ToString()

    Dim anzLabel As New Label
    anzLabel.Text = labelText
    anzeigeDiv.Controls.Add(anzLabel)

    Dim iButton2 As New Button
    iButton2.Text = xLauf.ToString
    iButton2.ID = "test" & xLauf.ToString()
    iButton2.CommandArgument = "1;"
    iButton2.CommandName = "1;"
    AddHandler iButton2.Command, AddressOf add
    anzeigeDiv.Controls.Add(iButton2)

    tbPanel.Controls.Add(anzeigeDiv)
End Sub
```

I've moved the add button, which will always exist, into the aspx page, so that the dynamic panel will only contain the buttons which have been added based on `gesStr` value.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic controls must be re-created in every postback see [this article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx) for more information.

Comment: thanks for your reply - i tried to adopt the hints the author gave - but it's not exactly what i am trying to achieve :( I would be very grateful if you could write down the missing script - but nevertheless thanks for your help :) as I will try to figure it out by myself as well ;)